# How do I log the XML that my proxy class sends to a web service?

Tags: c#, web-services

I generated a Proxy class from a WSDL URL. I can send requests to it, but I need to log the XML that gets sent. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Does this have to happen on the client side, or is a server side logging solution also acceptable?

Comment: I am not in control of the server side, so it would have to be client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this server-side by implementing the IDispatchMessageInspector as described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx). However, I believe that you can do the same thing client-side by implementing the [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) interface.

If I remember correctly, the [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms405951.aspx).ToString() method returns the SOAP which you can place straight into your log.

However, there is a gotcha which I *believe* is server-side only, but I'll mention it here as it may not be.

The Message class is designed to be read once only. Since you are intercepting the message to log it, you need to make sure that you avoid marking it as read as a side-effect. You have to clone it like so:

```
public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(
        ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(
        ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        // Create a buffer.
        MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);

        // Set the request reference to an unspoiled clone.
        request = buffer.CreateMessage();

        // Make another unspoiled clone to process (taint) locally within this method.
        Message originalMessage = buffer.CreateMessage();

        // Log the SOAP xml.
        Log(originalMessage.ToString());

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @My Other Me - Just curious, but was that gotcha a problem on the client-side? If not, I'll remove it from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also turn on SOAP logging, in case you are not using WCF:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esw638yk(VS.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esw638yk%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried that, but could not for the life of me get the Client side to log anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write code to do this yourself: just [configure WCF message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx)